# Java rectangle images

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am a bit new to Java and also to programming and in order to get beter at both the language and programming I decided to build a Monopoly Game.

I should also mention that this is my first project ever as a programmer so my way of doing things  may be very well the worst way.

I am using the Swing library and each Rectangle is drawn using graphics

I am building the layout using rectangles and I was wondering if there is a way to add diferent Images to each rectangle?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Swing components? More information is required to answer this question appropriately.

Comment: Please post (the important part of) your code.

Comment: @user985482: you should edit your question to give a bit more info.  Are you using Swing and a layout manager to somehow tile your rectangles?  It certainly *could* be done that way but for board games it's much more typical to build yourself one big image and process the elements/sprites/whatever inside that big image yourself (in your case each individual 'rectangle').

Comment: Yes I am using swing Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your panel with suitable layout, for ease I'd suggest you to use **JPanels with borders** rather than drawing rectangles.and follow these,

```
 image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
  JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Yayy! Now your image is a swing component ! add it to a frame or panel or anything like you usually do! Probably need a repainting too , like

```
  jpanel.add(picLabel);
  jpanel.repaint();
```

Do this for as many pics you want :) happy coding...cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to layout the board using Swing. If so, you can simply set the image icon of a `JLabel`.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( image ));
```

However, personally I would design the Monopoly board as a JPanel and write custom paint methods for it. In that case, you could proceed by simply using the `drawImage()` method of the `Graphics` class.

Answer (score 2):

What you might need to do is to create each rectangle as a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html). You can then use the [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) to create your grid and then set the background of the JPanel as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937403/jpanel-background-image).

You can also put a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) in each JPanel and use the [setIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) method as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddIcontoJLabel.htm).